# Do signal() and alarm() work even when the process where they are run is busy? Or should I run it on another dedicated process?

Tags: c, unix, signals, alarm

I am currently implementing a Producer/Consumers problem program. I have one parent and several child processes. Everything is working but now I need to make my program output each `k` milliseconds the progress of the task my program is doing.

At first I thought that maybe it'd be just about using the `signal()` and `alarm()` functions, but from some preliminary testing I've been making it doesn't seem enough. I have watched over several log files and it seems `onAlarm()` is not being called. I guess it has to do with the fact that as that both parent and children are "busy" they don't receive the events? Or even if they are busy, they should be able to receive calls on onAlarm()? The only workaround I see for this is to create yet another process, that has as single responsability dealing with this.

This is my "events" code:

```
void onAlarm() {
    signal(SIGALRM, onAlarm);
    alarm(0.01);

        fprintf(outputFile, "ALAAAAAAAAAAAAAARMMMMMMMMMMM: %d\n", numberOfBytesRead);
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGALRM, onAlarm);
    alarm(0.01);
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your main problem is that [`alarm()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/alarm.html) takes an integer number of seconds - and `alarm(0)` is used to cancel any outstanding alarms.

The natural follow-up question is:

> How can I do sub-second waiting?

I'm not sure what the approved way is.  On some systems, there is a micro-sleep (`usleep()`) call, but that is not part of POSIX 2008. The direct analogue of `usleep()` in POSIX appears to be [`nanosleep()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html).

There is a [`sigtimewait()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigtimedwait.html) which could probably be used to achieve the effect.  (You might be able to use [`setitimer()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setitimer.html) and `getitimer()` in lieu of `usleep()`.)

The difficulty with all of these is that you are either synchronous (you can't get on with work while waiting for a signal to arrive) or not sent a signal.  I don't immediately see a POSIX sub-second alarm mechanism, which would allow you to continue work while waiting for the timeout.

Comment: Use `setitimer` with the `ITIMER_REAL`.  Look for examples using this function.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether or not this is your problem, but it's not safe to `fprintf` inside a signal handler.  For example, the signal could be raised inside of `fprintf` itself, which might lead to unexpected behavior.  Or perhaps `fprintf` is allocating some memory, and the signal was caught while `malloc` was running.  This kind of thing can produce seemingly random deadlocks and violent crashes.

The safe way to do complex computations inside a signal handler is for your signal handler to alter the state of an already-running event loop, or something like this.  Or, for your specific problem, as others suggest, avoid using signals for this and use a more straightforward sleep call.

Comment: the `man` pages often say if a function is safe within a signal handler and sometimes say when it isn't.  Usually the extremely simple system calls (no IO) and calculating functions are safe.  If you know what you're doing you can get away with IO in signal handlers sometimes, but it's complicated.

Comment: @nategoose - You can definitely get away with I/O if only done through syscalls, but calling `stdio` is another story.  It manages read/write buffers in user mode and as I said a few years ago on this post, those might be an inconsistent state of you get a signal from inside a `stdio` function.  And it might allocate memory which is not safe for similar reasons.

Comment: @asveikay: "If you know what you're doing" encompasses a lot.  `fprintf(stderr,` may work, depending on how it's implemented, except that the signal handler calls to it may plop their output into the middle of other output.  This is usually tolerable for debug output.  Additionally, if you can avoid using heap and complex IO functions from the normal code, you usually can use them freely within the signal handlers.  You can also do that if you block/unblock signals around those functions within the normal code.  For small toy/test programs it's doable, but for large programs it becomes hard.

Comment: @nategoose  - I'm confused because we're pretty much saying similar things but you keep "disagreeing".  As I say "if done only through syscalls" - what I mean here is `write(2)` and nothing else.  `fprintf` is not a syscall.

Comment: @asveikay: All I'm saying is that sometimes, particularly in test or example code, you may see (or use) code that breaks the rule by using a function, such as `fprintf`, but will never result in corruption of memory or even messed up output. I mention this because example code on how signals work often uses `printf` family functions this way to demonstrate how the program execution flows.  The rule of not doing it is not a `never ever do this`, but it is a `you should almost never do this in code you expect to be reliable` rule.

Comment: @nategoose - I get it now.  Speaking personally, I tend to use the first rule as shorthand for the second.  :-)  The problem I have with this is to break a strict interpretation of the rules and hope for the best is a bit like leaving a timebomb in your code.  It's too easy to use signal handlers to create rare (but critical) issues in the field that you can never reproduce locally.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question is yes. They work even though the process they attached to is busy doing calculations or io/waiting of some sort. The only limitation is that the process is not changing and playing with `SIGALRM` itself which would cause problems. When a signal arrives the normal execution of a process/thread is suspended and the signal handler is called. That is the whole idea of signal handling and why it is called `asynchronous`.

The longer answer to your question is no. You wouldn't want to implement progress report via the signal handler mechanism since the API that you can use inside a signal handler is very limited. To be exact the example that you referred to wrong since it uses `fprintf(3)`. As has been stated in one of the replies signals are asynchronous. This means that if the signal arrives in the middle of the main code calling say, `malloc(3)`, and your code calls `malloc(3)` as well (you can never know, `printf(3)` may call `malloc(3)` for buffering and other needs) then you will corrupts mallocs own internal data structures and cause the program to fault. You may even have problems calling your own functions which are not async safe. You have a list of safe functions that you can call inside a signal handler and you can find those in `man 7 signal` under `Async-signal-safe functions`. So yes, technically you can implement progress reporting via `alarm(3)` as long as you are willing to live with this reduced API and that is the reason I would not do it unless the program is single threaded by design and unless there is really no way in which I see the progress reporting code as being subject to future enhancements that will make it hard to write inside a signal handler.

Another problem which has been stated about your example is that `alarm(2)` does not accept sub-second arguments and the example above should have failed compilation completely or at least showed some warnings about that fact.

For microsecond resolution you can use `setitimer(2)` with `ITIMER_REAL` as has been stated.

For nanosecond resolution on Linux you can use `timer_create(2)`, `CLOCK_REALTIME`, `SIGEV_SIGNAL` and `timer_settime(2)` that have many more features.

Here is some example code. Note that this uses my own error handling macros. You can see it in a compilable state in this project [demos-linux](https://github.com/veltzer/demos-linux/blob/master/src/examples/signals/progress_report_via_signal.cc)

```
#include <signal.h> // for signal(2), SIG_ERR
#include <unistd.h> // for alarm(2), write(2)
#include <stdlib.h> // for EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <err_utils.h>  // for CHECK_NOT_M1(), CHECK_NOT_SIGT()
#include <stdio.h>  // for snprintf(3), STDERR_FILENO
/*
 * This is an example of doing progress reports via the SIGALRM signal every second.
 * The main code does a tight calculation loop and the progress reporting to stderr
 * (file descriptor 2) is done via the alarm signal handler.
 */

/*
 * The variables are global to allow the signal handler to access them easily
 * You DONT need to initialize them to 0 since that is the default.
 * The 'volatile' on i is *critical* since it will be accessed asynchronously
 * and the compiler needs to know not to put it in a register since that
 * will mean that we cannot report it's value correctly from the signal
 * handler.
 */
volatile unsigned long i;
/*
 * Remember that this is a signal handler and calls to fprintf(3) or the like
 * are forbidden so we are forced to use async-safe function (see man 7 signal).
 * That is the reason for the cumbersome code. Hopefully snprintf(3) is safe enough
 * to use.
 */
static void handler(int sig) {
    // we have to reschedule the SIGALRM every time since the alarm(2)
    // is a one time deal.
    CHECK_NOT_SIGT(signal(SIGALRM, handler), SIG_ERR);
    // no error code from alarm(2)
    alarm(1);
    char buf[100];
    int len=snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "did [%ld] units of work...\n", i);
    CHECK_NOT_M1(write(STDERR_FILENO, buf, len));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp) {
    CHECK_NOT_SIGT(signal(SIGALRM, handler), SIG_ERR);
    // no error code from alarm(2)
    alarm(1);
    // a very long calculation
    while(true) {
        /* Do some real work here */
        i++;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need sub-second resolution on a timer, you can use a second posix thread and a `usleep`

Comment: There used to be a `ualarm` which could have done this, but POSIX don't like it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For a sub-second timer sending a signal, you need to use the POSIX setitimer(2) function.